# How can German supermarkets get away with not following the EU regulations, which have been established long ago?

Tags: european-union, germany, food

Since 2011, [EU regulations on food labeling](https://ec.europa.eu/food/safety/labelling_nutrition/labelling_legislation/nutrition-labelling_en) states require most foods label's to contain nutritional facts of the food.

However, as a person who has been living in Germany for a couple of months, it is quite clear to me that this regulation isn't followed in German supermarkets at all. Very few foods and drinks have their nutritional facts in their labels. Before Germany, I was living in UK, and there, everything had a label containing the nutritional facts of the food.

How can Germany, or German supermarket, get away with not following the EU regulations, which have been established long ago?

Comment: Because this question is based on your *perception* that the nutrition table might be missing on some packagings it is effectively impossible to answer. I just did a spot check in my fridge, and all the nutrition tables are there. Note that the table can also be on the back side or bottom of packaging, it doesn't have to be visible in the supermarket aisle.

Comment: Relevant German law: [Lebensmittelinformations-Durchführungsverordnung – LMIDV](https://www.buzer.de/s1.htm?g=Lebensmittelinformations-Durchf%C3%BChrungsverordnung+%E2%80%93+LMIDV&f=1).

Comment: In fact they are more commonly on the back and sides.

Comment: Based on a faulty observation

Comment: @Trish I know where that information is supposed to be; for a person who lived in UK for some time; to me, almost a quarter of items sold in the supermarkets doesn't have that info in label.

Comment: @wimh thanks but I don't know german, so can't understand what the law says exactly

Comment: Can you name a few common brands where you think the information is lacking?

Comment: @o.m. almost any wine in Lidl & Aldi, for example

Comment: To be honest, the only thing that is supposed to be inside a bottle of wine is wine. If they don't put anything else into the bottle I can't see why the big sign "wine" on the label isn't enough.

Comment: @gnasher729, it would be quite relevant to list the caloric value of beer.

Comment: Did any wine you bought in the UK have nutrition information on the label?

Comment: @phoog yes, all of them!

Answer (score 11):

You are referring to article 9 of [Regulation (EU) No 1169/2011](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02011R1169-20180101) which contains:

> Article 9 List of mandatory particulars
>
> 1. In accordance with Articles 10 to 35 and subject to the exceptions contained in this Chapter, indication of the following particulars shall be mandatory:
>
> (...)
>
> (l) a nutrition declaration.

In a comment you clarify that you are talking about wine.

Article 16 of [Regulation (EU) No 1169/2011](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02011R1169-20180101) contains:

> Article 16 Omission of certain mandatory particulars
>
> (...)
>
> 4. Without prejudice to other Union provisions requiring a list of ingredients or a mandatory nutrition declaration, the particulars referred to in points (b) and (l) of Article 9(1) shall not be mandatory for beverages containing more than 1,2 % by volume of alcohol.

As wine contains typically more than 1,2 % alcohol, a nutrition declaration is not required.

See also [Labelling of alcoholic beverages in the EU: some facts](https://ec.europa.eu/food/safety/labelling_nutrition/labelling_legislation/alcohol_en).

Answer (score 3):

You clarified in the comments that some examples are wine.

According to German law implementing EU law, [alcoholic drinks](https://www.bzfe.de/inhalt/naehrwertkennzeichnung-1876.html) are not covered by the nutrition labeling requirement. [Consumer groups](https://www.deutschlandfunknova.de/beitrag/bier-wein-schnaps-naehrwertangaben-fehlen-bisher) demand going beyond EU requirements in this regard, but it hasn't happened yet.